ESP32, BQ25895 sharing usb data lines
Im building a portable device with a ESP32-S3 which will be interfaced with a SD card, and a BQ25895 charge controller. The ESP32 will connect to the computer as a mass storage device. The BQ25895 will charge an internal battery, however I want to only use one USB C port. Can I connect the USB data lines of the 2 chips together or do I need a multiplexer, or is there some way the two esp and BQ25895 together to share data?
